# Java 8 Stream - iterate over multiple lists and concatenate the answer

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

My issue is the following:
I have a ListA and an ENUM. I would like to iterate over ListA and for each element from ListA apply a method get(value) where value is an ENUM. All this processing should return an object of type T.
What I have now is:

```
default void processLists(P<?, ?, T> p) {
 T allData = (T) Stream.of(Vvalues.values())
            .map(c -> p.get(c.name()))
            .flatMap(optionalData -> optionalData.map(data -> ((List<T>) data).stream()).orElse(Stream.empty()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    save(allData);
}
```

....
    getListA().stream().forEach(p->processLists(p));

The code (as posted in the comments):

```
getUrls().stream().forEach(url->processUrl(url)); 

default void processUrl(Url<?, ?, T> url) {
    T allData = (T) Stream.of(Location.values()) 
        .map(location -> url.get(location.name())) 
        .flatMap(optionalData -> optionalData
            .map(data -> ((List<T>) data).stream())
            .orElse(Stream.empty()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList()); 
    save(allData); 
 }
```

This is not ok as I would like to call save just ONCE.

Comment: `Collectors.toList()` will never return an object of type `T`

Comment: You could post your code. Your procedure code cannot be understood

Comment: You talk ayout listA and litsB, but don't see any list in your code

Comment: getUrls().stream()
        .forEach(url->processUrl(url));


default void processUrl(Url<?, ?, T> url) {
    T allData = (T) Stream.of(Location.values())
            .map(location -> url.get(location.name()))
            .flatMap(optionalData -> optionalData.map(data -> ((List<T>) data).stream()).orElse(Stream.empty()))
     .collect(Collectors.toList());
    save(allData);
}

Comment: Why don't you just adjust your `processUrl` method to accept `Collection<Url<?, ?, T> url)` and `flatMap` the parameter in there?

Comment: how? Can you post an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand correctly you problem, you have an `Enum` and some other class, i.e. `Data`:

```
enum Enum {}

class Data {

    public String get(Enum value) {
        return value.name();
    }

}
```

All you need, is just call `Data.get(Enum)` with all available constants from `Enum`. As result for each item from source list, you get list of results and you want to retrieve all these data as simple list.

```
public static List<String> process(List<Data> data) {
    return data.stream()
               .map(d -> Arrays.stream(Enum.values()).map(d::get).collect(Collectors.toList()))
         //    .map(d -> Arrays.stream(Enum.values()).map(e -> d.get(e.name())).collect(Collectors.toList()))
               .flatMap(List::stream)
               .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

*This is example of the client code:*

```
List<String> res = process(new ArrayList<>());
```

Comment: You are right just one correction class Data {

    public String get(String value) {//value can be all possible values from enum
        return value; //just for test
    }

}

Comment: if get(String value) then I cannot call map(d::get)...:(

Comment: `.map(d -> Arrays.stream(Enum.values()).map(e -> d.get(e.name())).collect(Collectors.toList()))`